# How to Parse an JS Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following information:

1. The **city name**, in this case Littelside. This is stored in a variable `var city`
2. I have an array of {} objects. Each contains address, city, name, state and zip-code

`[{"address":"07288 Albertha Station",**"city":"Littelside"**,"created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{NEXT OBJECT WITH ADDRESS CITY ETC}]`

How do you use the `var city` as a search term to parse the array, and return address, city, state, name and zip of the **array with the matching city**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myarr  =  [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Mr. Emmitt Emmerich","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","zip":"75475-9938"}];
var city = 'Littelside';
$.each(myarr,function(key,value){
    if(value['city']== city){
        alert('hello');
    }
})
```

here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/dTEJX/)

Comment: books no... who needs books when you have the internet... I try not to write any native js try to use jquery as much as possible you can find [documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) its been truly more helpful than any book i've read

Comment: @JZ Javascript: The Good Parts from Douglas Crockford is a must :).

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

```
var city='Littelside';

var cucc=$.grep(your_array, function (a) {
    return a.city==search;
})[0];
```

`$.grep` will still return an array, with all the elements inside that satisify the filter function. Here I've use `[0]` to get the first result, which is fine in case you're sure that there will be one result. So `cucc` will have the whole object you're looking for.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gqcwa/)

Answer (score 1):

A function I use.

```
function arrayIndexOfProp(arr, prop, obj) {
        var i = arr.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (arr[i] && arr[i][prop] === obj) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

var index = arrayIndexOfProp(theArray, "city","Littelside");
// do stuff with theArray[index]
```

Comment: thanks! a tiny bit of cleverness to save a few chars over a for loop :)

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as in

```
Array.prototype.reduce(
    function (prev, current) {
      return prev || current.city === "Littelside" ? current : null;
    })
```

Comment: Browser support is not really there AFAIK, but still +1.

Comment: @bazmegakap, You are correct that it is not yet widely supported.  The compatibility section (link follows) does have code that you can use to back-port it onto older browsers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility

Answer (score -1):

Loop over the array until you find one where `the_array[i].city` matches.